# Precompiled header error in compiling c/c++ mixture with JNI in VS2015

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am playing around with JNI(Java native Interface) following the tutorial as below

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Specifically, I am trying to build 2.2-JNI with c/c++ miture, in Visual Studio 2015. I wrote the codes as instructed and put them in a toy win32 console application project. Somehow, when I tried to build it, the following error pops:

"Error  C1853   'x64\Release\ConsoleApplication1.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)".

This image shows the crime scene.

[image]

Any ideas of why this comes out?

Comment: The C/C++ mix could probably be a problem, as hinted to by the error message. You might have to disable precompiled headers, unless it's possible to use different precompiled headers for the C and C++ files?

Comment: Thanks man, I disabled the pch for the .c file and it went through. :)